# cyclic drawing in KeyboardView

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

I have class

```
public class OwnKeyboardView extends KeyboardView {
...
}
```

Its have override method OnDraw:

```
@Override
    public void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    mCanvas = draw_bitmap(canvas);
    Draw_Bitmap(mCanvas);
}
```

Class KeyboardView Inherited Methods

From class android.view.View

From class java.lang.Object

**From interface android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.Callback**

Method OnDraw working at press any key.

When i do next:

```
public Canvas draw_bitmap(Canvas canvas) {

        if (mCanvas != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Copy Canvas");
        }
        return canvas;
    }
```

Why in method **OnDraw** i can draw with **mCanvas**, but other don't can? I want cycle drawing on Keyboard, but OnDraw work only when you press on keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoy may create Thread and in the Thread manually call postInvalidate, like this.

Note: It will drain the battery much

```
boolean flag=true;
private void Thread_Draw(){

       new Thread(new Runnable(){

            public void run(){

               while(flag)
               {
                    postInvalidate();
                    try{
                       Thread.sleep(45);
                    } catch(InterruptedException e)
                    {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                    }
               }
            }
      }
}
```

Stop thread you can from method

```
public void stopThread(boolean bool)
{
     flag=bool;
}
```

read about PostInvalidate yom can this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate()